# How to indefinitely read an unbounded channel in a Rust Tokio task?

Tags: rust, channel, rust-tokio

I assumed that `.for_each()` would do the trick, but it returns only the first (future) item from the channel and then returns, if the channel is empty. What would be the way to indefinitely read a channel in a task as `.for_each()` would do in non-Tokio/future context?

```
let tx_origs_reader = rx_chan.for_each(move |tx_orig| {
    //save receiver side tx to db
    let mut tx_origs_once = tx_origs_inner.borrow_mut();
    tx_origs_once.push(tx_orig.clone());  
    Ok(())
});
handle.spawn(tx_origs_reader.then(|err| {
    println!("This returns after first item without an error {:?}", err);
    Ok(())
}));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question would be more likely to be answered in a reasonable amount of time if you provide a [MCVE]. As it is right now, you are requiring that *each* potential answerer construct a complete program from scratch, **guessing** at the types of every variable you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for_each` way of handling is the best way, should work - and it works! It was debugged to be a problem in the tx side with the help of tokio-rs people in Gitter (thanks!) with simple test code.

It seems to me that Rust was so advanced, that it actually knew to drop the task in this case: the logging output based on this confused me to actually think that problem was on rx side, although it was tx side problem all along.